# Why is my plot data getting condensed when using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I am converting .csv files into panda data frames. When I plot the data frames using python, my data is condensed. Attached is the picture of the figure produced by matplotlib and the other by excel. The range of the data in excel is from 0 to 140 hours.

[image: 1]

However on the figure generated in python, it is only 0 to 75 hours.

[image: 2]

Here is a snippet of the code:
# how the csv file is opened
with open(file,'r') as csv_file:
df=pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=None,names=columns,usecols=['Timestamp','Sensor 5 (DO)','O2'])
df.drop(index=df.index[0],axis=0,inplace=True)

```
#This plots two columns on the same plot
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

plt_1 = ax1.plot(df['Timestamp'],df['Sensor 5 (DO)'],'ro',label='Sensor 5 (DO)',)
plt_2 = ax2.plot(df['Timestamp'],df['O2'],'ko',label='O2')

leg = plt_1 + plt_2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in leg]

ax1.legend(leg, labs)

ax1.set_xlabel("Time")
ax1.set_ylabel("DO Saturation (%)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Sparged Oxygen Flow Rate (sccm)")
```

Example set of datahead:

,Timestamp,Sensor 5 (DO),O2
1,4/13/2021 10:32,,
2,4/13/2021 10:33,67.89,0
3,4/13/2021 10:33,69.21,0
4,4/13/2021 10:34,71.66,0
5,4/13/2021 10:34,72.92,0
6,4/13/2021 10:35,74.41,0
7,4/13/2021 10:35,76.04,0
8,4/13/2021 10:36,77.61,0
9,4/13/2021 10:36,79.3,0
10,4/13/2021 10:37,81.02,0
11,4/13/2021 10:37,82.85,0
12,4/13/2021 10:38,84.52,0
13,4/13/2021 10:38,86.3,0
14,4/13/2021 10:39,88.1,0
15,4/13/2021 10:39,89.61,0

Tail:
,Timestamp,Sensor 5 (DO),O2
17353,4/19/2021 11:11,100,0
17354,4/19/2021 11:11,100,0
17355,4/19/2021 11:12,100,0
17356,4/19/2021 11:12,100,0
17357,4/19/2021 11:13,100,0
17358,4/19/2021 11:13,100,0
17359,4/19/2021 11:14,100,0
17360,4/19/2021 11:14,100,0
17361,4/19/2021 11:15,100,0
17362,4/19/2021 11:15,100,0
17363,4/19/2021 11:16,100,0
17364,4/19/2021 11:16,100,0
17365,4/19/2021 11:17,100,0
17366,4/19/2021 11:17,100,0
17367,4/19/2021 11:18,100,0

Comment: Does the Timestamp value range from 0 to 140 or from 0 to 75. So does the data have 141 entries or 76?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a few rows of data (in text format using a text editor not Excel) from your CSV file. We would then be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @BigBen the t_rows is the total number of rows in the dataframe. In this case it would be 17000 data points. I added that line of code to determine if it was an x-axis issue.

Comment: @ai2ys The data is captured in 30 second intervals over the span of 6 days. So like I stated there is ~17000 data points. Setting the x axis tick marks in 20 hour intervals is preferred.